# Excel Opens Two Instances

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

A user in my department just got a refresh.  Whenever she opens an excel document it appears to open two separate instances of Excel (2013).  One that contains her spreadsheet and one that is just the active program, without an active document.  I did a repair on the MS Office to no avail.  Anyone have a fix for this.

[image]

Comment: What happens when she starts excel (start, run, `excel.exe`) or via the start menu. If that works as expected then it is likely in the connection from .xls to staring excel.

Comment: Agreed, you might want to check the template or even the personal macro workbook

Comment: Does she have the preview pane turned on in explorer? Known issue with no fix if so, I'm afraid.

Comment: Does this happen to all Excel files? Or only certain ones? If you close the second window, save the file, then close it, does it still open two windows?